# Creating a New List of Items With Numbers >= 60 from A List of Items Numbered 0 to 100

Tags: python, web-scraping, html-lists, custom-lists

The items in the list are movie titles with a 0 to 100 rating next to them. Here's part of it...

```
[(u'The Girl on the Train', 43),
(u'Keeping Up With The Joneses', 19),
(u'Ouija: Origin of Evil', 82),
(u'Long Way North (Tout en haut du monde)', 98),
(u'The Whole Truth', 29),
(u'Come And Find Me', 67),
(u'LEGO Jurassic World: The Indominus Escape', None),
(u'My Father, Die', 78)...]
```

I'd like to make a list of movies with scores at or above 60. Here is one of the things I've tried that didn't work, (this code will pull a little bit of data from RottenTomatoes website, FYI)...

```
import requests

r = requests.get('https://www.rottentomatoes.com/api/private/v2.0/browse?page=1&limit=30&type=dvd-top-rentals&services=amazon%3Bamazon_prime%3Bfandango_now%3Bhbo_go%3Bitunes%3Bn    etflix_iw%3Bvudu&sortBy=popularity')


list = []
data = r.json()
for result in data["results"]:
    list.append((result["title"], result["tomatoScore"]))

list2 = [i for i in list if i >=60]

print list2
```

I would also like to have all my movies titles with a score at or above 60 to be truncated to just the text of the movie title so I can have a program that enters them into search fields of websites. So if you know how that's done that would save me some additional feeling around in the dark. Maybe just a hint how that's done if asking how to do that is asking too much.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
list2 = [i for i in list if i >= 60]
```

to

```
list2 = [i for i in list if i[1] >= 60]. # You need to compare only ratings
```

And don't call your list `list`. It will overwrite python `list`.

Comment: @Ant Please read [python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/index.html) before asking questions on SO.

Answer (score 0):

Good question:

Perhaps, this would help you:

```
for i, j in list:
    if j >= 60:
        print j
```

This prints only the value of above 60. If you want to append it in a list, then use:

```
for i, j in list:
    if j >= 60:
        list2.append(j)
```

Hope that works!

Comment: Note that I think you mean print i and list2.append(i), and since we're using python and not whatever archaic language (cobol, fortran?) required single character variables, I'd suggest for title,rank in list ... as well as using Yevhen's answer's more pythonic style of list comprehensions

Comment: I'm using Python. I did like Yevhen's answer. I couldn't get the other one to work. Does do what Yevhen suggested turn my list into a tuple, or was it a tuple to begin with? How can I change it back to a list?